# Convert email to http request with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http, email, request

Is there a way to send http request (to a specific url address) each time i receive email (Google account), with the content of the email received using Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, it seems that you already have an Incoming Email Handler in your App Engine application.

If the above is true, then in the Incoming Email Handler, you can parse out the message and if it meets your condition for invoking the http request, then you can definitely do that. You can use the `URL Fetch` service for the same.

One design decision you might want to do is whether you want to keep all your URL Fetch code inside of the incoming Email Handler or you want that to be handled externally via a Task Queue. In that case, I suggest that you can use the Task Queue to create a task when an incoming email comes in to your handler. Then the Task Queue logic can take care of one or more things, which includes invoking the HTTP Service, as you wanted.